# How would I turn this for loop output into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have this code and I am having trouble figuring out how to put the for loop output into a dataframe. How could I take the for loop data and put it into a Pandas DataFrame?

Rows look like
('tag', 34)

```
select_stmt = select(Tag.tag, func.count('Tag.tag').label('CCount')).group_by(Tag.tag)
with Session(config.connect()) as session:
    exec = session.execute(select_stmt)
    for row in exec:
        print(row)
```

Comment: How does the `row` look like? You could add all the rows on a list with .append, then after the loop, create a dataframe with that list, like pd.DataFrame(list)

Comment: You want a single column with the tag values? It may be helpful to simplify the question by creating a test list of tuples in `exec`.

Comment: Perhaps `df = pd.DataFrame({"tag":[row[1] for row in exec})`

Comment: @EmmanuelMurairi Brilliant idea. I went with a dict instead because I only have two columns here. Works pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by turning data into a dict since I only have two columns. Note this gives you a column for each pair and not a row. You can fix that with `dd.transpose()`.

```
select_stmt = select(Tag.tag, func.count('Tag.tag').label('CCount')).group_by(Tag.tag)
with Session(config.connect()) as session:
    exec = session.execute(select_stmt)
    row_dict = {row.tag: [row.CCount] for row in exec}
    dd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row_dict)
    ddd = dd.transpose()
    return ddd
```

Comment: Consider dict comprehension and avoid bookkeeping: `row_dict = {row.name: [row.CCount] for row in exec}`

Comment: I don't follow your point?

Comment: Consider replacing your first four lines with what I suggested. (I renamed your dic as row_dict).

Comment: That doesn't explain the why or your reasoning in general. Or what the terms you used mean.

Comment: By bookkeeping, I mean the need to initialize the dictionary variable and call update per iteration. With comprehension (often considered _pythonic_ in style), you do all in one step and can be faster processing. Sorry for confusion. Again, just a consideration. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. I'll update answer in a bit after I test. Thanks again.

Comment: @Parfait - it works. I didn't know you could build a dict in place like that. Thanks.